# Pie chart not displaying in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: crystal-reports

I generate a Pie chart from my Crystal Report in HTML format, in order to display it in a browser. But the generated HTML displays pie chart in IE browser and not in other browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Because Generated HTML from the crystal report Generates below HTML and those browser does not support `filer: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader` css property.

HTML Generated from the Crystal Report:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="Author" content="Crystal Reports 11.0">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <style>    div {position:absolute; z-index:25}
         a {text-decoration:none}
         a img {border-style:none; border-width:0}
         .adi81ru1gam9ps-0 {border-color:#000000;border-left-width:0;border-right-width:0;border-top-width:0;border-bottom-width:0;}
      </style>
      <div style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,1008px,634px,0px);top:0px;left:0px;width:1008px;height:634px;"></div>
      <div class="adi81ru1gam9ps-0" nowrap="true" style="z-index:15;top:0px;left:2px;width:954px;height:619px;">
         <div style="width:954px;height:619px;display:inline-block;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true,sizingMethod=scale,src='{AB1B3FFD-B011-40CB-A39A-E1CE1EC51450}{C96C12A1-A23A-41FA-8373-D35B5496BDE2}.png');"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

To make this work in Chrome or other major browsers, I have to add below CSS in DIV element:

```
 background:url(image url);  
-moz-background-size:cover; 
-webkit-background-size:cover; 
 background-size:cover;
```

We don't have any control on the HTML which generates from the crystal report. How can I resolve this?